# Prove that $\frac{d}{dx}(xJ_\alpha(x)J_{\alpha+1}(x))=x(J_\alpha^2(x)-J_{\alpha+1}^2(x))$

Tags: bessel-functions

Assume that $J_\alpha(x)$ is defined as below:   (Actually, It's one of the solutions of Bessel's ODE)
 $J_\alpha(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n! \Gamma(n+\alpha+1)}(\frac{x}{2})^{2n+\alpha}$

Such that $\Gamma(x)=\int_0^{+\infty} t^{x-1} e^{-t}dt$.

We know that (i) & (ii) hold.

(i) $\frac{d}{dx}(x^\alpha J_\alpha(x))=x^\alpha J_{\alpha-1}(x)$
(ii) $\frac{d}{dx}(x^{-\alpha} J_\alpha(x))=-x^{-\alpha}J_{\alpha+1}(x)$

**Question**:

Using (i) and (ii), Prove that:

> a) $J'_\alpha(x)=\frac{1}{2}(J_{\alpha-1}(x)-J_{\alpha+1}(x))$
>   b) $\frac{2\alpha}{x}J_{\alpha}(x)=J_{\alpha-1}(x)+J_{\alpha+1}(x)$
>   c) $\frac{d}{dx}(xJ_\alpha(x)J_{\alpha+1}(x))=x(J_\alpha^2(x)-J_{\alpha+1}^2(x))$

**My try:**

a)  First, I calculated the derivative of the LHS of (i) and then multiplied the whole equation by $x^{-\alpha}$. I did the same thing for (ii) and then multiplied it by $x^\alpha$. The summation of these two equations gives the desired result.

b) I solved it similar to a, with a tiny difference. (Multiplying by $-x^\alpha) $

I'm stuck on proving (c). I wrote a lot but it didn't work out...

Any idea?

Comment: Just for reference, here are two other questions which ask to prove the same identity, but do not provide identities (i) and (ii): [Prove equation using Bessel functions: $\frac{d}{dx}[xJ_n(x)J_{n+1}(x)]=x[J_n^{2}(x)-J_{n+1}^{2}(x)]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1880698/prove-equation-using-bessel-functions-fracddxxj-nxj-n1x-xj-n2) and [Bessel function equation with derivation: $\frac{d}{dx} (xJ_{\alpha}(x)J_{\alpha+1}(x)) = x(J_{\alpha}^2(x)-J_{\alpha +1}^2(x))$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1608259/bessel-function-equation-with-derivation-fracddx-xj-alphaxj-alpha)

Comment: Since you are provided the two identities (i) and (ii), which makes the question a lot easier, I suggest not closing this question as a duplicate.

Comment: @projectilemotion Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d} x}\left(x\text{J}_{\alpha}(x)\text{J}_{\alpha+1}(x)\right)=$$

---

Use the product rule, $\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}(uv)=v\frac{\text{d}u}{\text{d}x}+u\frac{\text{d}v}{\text{d}x}$, where $u=x$ and $v=\text{J}_{\alpha}(x)$:

---

$$\text{J}_{\alpha}(x)\text{J}_{1+\alpha}(x)\left[\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}(x)\right]+x\left[\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(\text{J}_{\alpha}(x)\text{J}_{1+\alpha}(x)\right)\right]=$$
$$\text{J}_{\alpha}(x)\text{J}_{1+\alpha}(x)\left[1\right]+x\left[\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(\text{J}_{\alpha}(x)\text{J}_{1+\alpha}(x)\right)\right]=$$
$$\text{J}_{\alpha}(x)\text{J}_{1+\alpha}(x)+x\left[\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(\text{J}_{\alpha}(x)\text{J}_{1+\alpha}(x)\right)\right]=$$

---

Use the product rule, $\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}(uv)=v\frac{\text{d}u}{\text{d}x}+u\frac{\text{d}v}{\text{d}x}$, where $u=\text{J}_{\alpha}(x)$ and $v=\text{J}_{\alpha+1}(x)$:

---

$$\text{J}_{\alpha}(x)\text{J}_{1+\alpha}(x)+x\left[\text{J}_{1+\alpha}(x)\cdot\frac{\text{J}_{\alpha-1}-\text{J}_{1+\alpha}(x)}{2}+\text{J}_{\alpha}(x)\left[\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(\text{J}_{1+\alpha}(x)\right)\right]\right]=$$
$$\text{J}_{\alpha}(x)\text{J}_{1+\alpha}(x)+x\left[\text{J}_{1+\alpha}(x)\cdot\frac{\text{J}_{\alpha-1}-\text{J}_{1+\alpha}(x)}{2}+\text{J}_{\alpha}(x)\left[\frac{1}{2}\left(\text{J}_{\alpha}(x)-\text{J}_{2+\alpha}(x)\right)\right]\right]=$$
$$x\left[\text{J}_{\alpha}^2(x)-\text{J}_{1+\alpha}^2(x)\right]$$

Answer (score 4):

Here is an easy method using only the two identities you are given at the start of the question.

---

Notice that:
$$\color{red}{x^{\alpha+1}J_{\alpha+1}(x)}\cdot \color{blue}{x^{-\alpha} J_\alpha(x)}=xJ_{\alpha}(x)J_{\alpha+1}(x)$$
Therefore, we can apply the product rule with $u=x^{\alpha+1}J_{\alpha+1}(x)$ and $v=x^{-\alpha}J_{\alpha}(x)$:
$$\begin{align}(uv)'&=u'v+uv'\\&=(x^{\alpha+1}J_{\alpha+1}(x))'\cdot x^{-\alpha}J_{\alpha}(x)+x^{\alpha+1}J_{\alpha+1}(x)\cdot (x^{-\alpha}J_{\alpha}(x))'  \end{align}$$
Substituting (i) and (ii) and simplifying gives the required identity:
$$x^{\alpha+1}J_{\alpha}(x)\cdot x^{-\alpha}J_{\alpha}(x)+x^{\alpha+1}J_{\alpha+1}(x)\cdot -x^{-\alpha}J_{\alpha+1}(x)=x(J_{\alpha}^2(x)-J_{\alpha+1}^2(x))$$